# Convergence in weighted $L^2$ space

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that we have $f_j\to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and in addition, $f_j$ satisfies
$$
\int{|f_j(x)|e^{a|x|^2} dx}\leq M
$$
for some $a>0$, and $M>0$.
Is it true that we have then $\int{|f(x)|e^{b|x|^2} dx}<\infty$ with  $0<b<a$?

Comment: Are we assuming $f_i \geq 0$?

Comment: @ PhoemueX, sorry, I forgot to put |.|

Comment: @PhoemueX Your (presently deleted) proof still works, if applied to $|f_j|$.

Comment: @Thursday: Thanks, I restored the post. I deleted it because I noticed the missing positivity assumption and I was pretty sure that the claim is wrong without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_N = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon e^{2b |x|^2 } < N \} $ and let $j = j(N) \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\| f - f_j \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} < \frac{1}{m(E_N) N^2}$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, we have that
\begin{align}
\int |f(x)| e^{b |x|^2} dx 
&\leq  \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{E_N} |f(x)-f_j(x)| e^{b |x|^2} dx + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f_j(x) | e^{b |x|^2} dx\\
&\leq  \lim_{N \to \infty} \| f-f_j \|_{L^2(E_N)} \| \int_{E_N} e^{2b |x|^2} dx + M \\
& \leq \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{m(E_N) N^2} N m(E_N) + M \\
& = M < \infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least assuming $f_j \geq 0$, the claim is even true for $b=a$. By $L^2$ convergence, we have $f_{n_k} \to f$ pointwise a.e. for a suitable subsequence. Apply Fatou's Lemma.

EDIT: Apply the above to $|f_j|$ instead of $f_j$.